# haskell add anything to a existing function

Tags: function, haskell, addition

hey there using this script:

```
smallestDifference3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallestDifference3 a b c
    | ((differenceAB < differenceBC) && (differenceBC < differenceAC)) = differenceAB
    | ((differenceAB < differenceAC) && (differenceAC < differenceBC)) = differenceAB
    | ((differenceBC < differenceAB) && (differenceAB < differenceAC)) = differenceBC
    | ((differenceBC < differenceAC) && (differenceAC < differenceAB)) = differenceBC
    | ((differenceAC < differenceBC) && (differenceBC < differenceAB)) = differenceAC
    | ((differenceAC < differenceAB) && (differenceBC < differenceBC)) = differenceAC
  where differenceAB 
         | a < b = -(a - b)
         | otherwise    = a - b
        differenceBC
         | b < c = -(b - c)
         | otherwise    = b - c
        differenceAC
         | a < c = -(a - c)
         | otherwise    = a - c
```

i can type three Integers and get the smallest result of two of these Integer´s.
but what can i do if i add one more INT, so i have:

```
smallestDifference4 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallestDifference4 a b c d

// etc..
```

Should i use the "smallestDifference3"-function to get this or what do i need to do? greetings!

Comment: In the last guard you wrote `differenceBC < differenceBC`, which will never be true.

Comment: You will also have problems if any of the differences are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a generic function which takes a *list*, i.e.

```
smallestDifference :: [Int] -> Int
```

and then use that from your other functions, e.g.

```
smallestDifference4 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallestDifference4 a b c d = smallestDifference [a,b,c,d]
```

...of course, at that point you might want to just drop those tiny functions altogether since they don't "pull their own weight".

That being said, you could implement this function more in terms of existing functions. The idea is that you need a way to get all possible pairs for the given list, then compute the difference of the pair members, and then pick the minimum of that.

You would need an 'all pairs' function like

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs = concat . go
  where go [] = []
        go [x] = []
        go (x:xs) = map (\a -> (x,a)) xs : go xs
```

and then you could do it like

```
smallestDifference = minimum
                   . map abs
                   . map (uncurry (-))
                   . pairs
```

Comment: i am not sure what u exactly mean, where should i implement the "smallestDifference3"-function ? but thanks for joining this thread:)

Comment: i upvoted your post, cause i think you´re doing it the right way, but i cant add it in my code, sorry:/

Comment: `smallestDifference xs = minimum [ abs (x-y) | x:ys <- tails xs, y <- ys ]`

Comment: @augustss Oops, and here I thought I was doing a reasonable job already... I didn't think of using `tails`!